# getIntExtra always returns default

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Please help me I don't understand what is wrong with this..
the value of k in called activity is always one.

**My Calling activity code**

```
            pos_st = position;
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(branch.this, BranchInfo.class);
            lk= idnum[pos_st];
            int x=Integer.parseInt(lk);
            newActivity.putExtra("idnumber",x);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "X :" + x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(newActivity);
```

**Called Activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
int k =intent.getIntExtra("idnumber",1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to create a `new Intent()` in the called activity.

Instead try the following to get the same `Intent` that was used to start the `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int k = intent.getIntExtra("idnumber", 1);
```

Comment: i did that now I am getting this error: E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: At what point are you calling `getIntent()`? Make sure it is in `onCreate()` or later in the `Activity`.